# Typescript with Babylonjs built with Webpack error: Duplicate identifier 'BABYLON'

Tags: typescript, webpack, babylonjs

I'm working on a webgl RTS game called [density wars](https://github.com/QuantumInformation/Density-Wars), but I am getting lots of errors like the following:

`ERROR in [default] /Users/nikos/PhpstormProjects/Density-Wars/babylonjs.d.ts:1:15 
Duplicate identifier 'BABYLON'.`

In my entry point to typescript I do this:

```
/// <reference path="./gameUnits/Core.ts" />
/// <reference path="./utils/UnitCommand.ts" />
/// <reference path="./utils/Formations.ts" />
/// <reference path="./User.ts" />
declare function require(module: string):any

require('../style.css');
var BABYLON = require('babylonjs');
```

webpack.config:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/lib",
  entry: {
    main: [
      "./game.ts"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "density-wars.js"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('file') instead of require('file.js')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Duplicate identifier 'BABYLON'

Because of your code `var BABYLON = require('babylonjs');`. In the absence of a root level `import` or `export` the file is contributing to the *global* namespace and thus you have multiple `var BABYLON` declarations.

## Fix

use `import BABYLON = require('babylonjs');` Or at least `export` something from the file that has the `var BABYLON`.

More https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: Thanks for your help basarat for some reason I can't use **import BABYLON from 'babylonjs'** from  `https://github.com/QuantumInformation/Density-Wars/blob/master/lib/game.ts#L10`,  I am getting the error **Cannot find module 'babylonjs'.** I have installed it in package.com